# How do I make my function call stay in context?

Tags: python, flask

I have a class that is trying to call an RPC from a server, using the name_me method defined on the server. It works fine if I call it in iPython using:

```
jsonrpcclient.request ('http://localhost:5000', 'name_me', N=6).data.result
```

but when I try to build it with my class, I get the error:

```
RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.
```

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
an active HTTP request.  Consult the documentation on testing for
information about how to avoid this problem.

I'll put the client code in the code section.

```
class LyricCaller:

    def __update_host_port (self, new_port):
        self.__port = new_port

    def __update_host_address (self, new_address):
        self.__address = new_address

    def __target (self):
        return '{}:{}'.format (self.__address, self.__port)

    def __init__(self, host_address = 'http://localhost:5000', host_port = 5000):
        self.lyric = []
        self.__Lyr_fn = 'name_me'
        self.__update_host_address (host_address)
        self.__update_host_port (host_port)

    def __parse_choice (self, choice):
        return abs (choice)


    def sing(self):
        print (self.lyric)

    def fetch_lyric (self, choice):
        C = self.__parse_choice (choice)
        K = request (self.__target(), self.Lyr_fn, N=1)
```

I expect a returned string, which works when I just directly call
jsonrpcclient.request ('http://localhost:5000', 'name_me', N=6).data.result,

but instead I still get the context error. I've tried restarting the server, but still the same thing occurs.

for further reference, here's the server code:

'''

```
from flask import Flask, request, Response
from jsonrpcserver import method, dispatch

LServer = Flask(__name__)

@method
def name_me (N = 1):
    K = ['How do we sleep while our beds are burning?',
         'You label me, I label you, and so I dub thee Unforgiven', 
         'Carry on my wayward son!',
         'Not dead which eternal lie, stranger aeons death may die',
         'Let the bodies hit the floor', 
         'Wollt ihr das bed in flammen siehen']

    #N = 4
    if N <= len (K):
        O = K[N-1] 
    else:
        import random
        n = random.randint (0, len(K)-1)
        O = K[n]

    return O

@LServer.route ('/', methods = ['POST'])
def index():
    #with LServer.test_request_context():
        req = request.get_data().decode()
        response = dispatch(req)
        return Response (str(response), response.http_status, mimetype="application/json")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    LServer.run()
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

The Flask [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/reqcontext/) says:
If you see that error somewhere else in your code not related to testing, it most likely indicates that you should move that code into a view function.

So your code will be similar to this:

```
from flask.views import View

# ...

class Index(View):

    def dispatch_request(self):
        req = request.get_data().decode()
        response = dispatch(req)
        return Response (str(response), response.http_status, mimetype="application/json")


LServer.add_url_rule('/', 'index', view_func=Index.as_view('index'),methods=['POST'])
```

Comment: I don't get it - app is defined by the server, not the client. How do I call the context from the client?

Comment: sorry. I edit my answer. you should add this code on the server.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense. I'll test that out right away... <coding away> so now its out of context from both the class and the iPython console.

Comment: try it this with current_app.test_request_context():

Comment: current_app does not exist?

Comment: Off to home, I'll check back tomorrow. Thanks for trying

Comment: So the server fires up fine, but I get the context error calling from either iPython or from the class.